File at path: '/amplify-vite-react-template/amplify/.config/project-config.json' does not exist
I created a vite react app and added authentication and it is working fine. However now I wish to use amplify add api and I am getting the following error:
 File at path: '/amplify-vite-react-template/amplify/.config/project-config.json' does not exist
I am basically following the tutorial here:
https://docs.amplify.aws/react/start/quickstart/
